# Access an identity (certificate+private key) in keychain added using iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ssl-certificate, keychain

for an iOS/iPad application i'm developing i need to use an ssl certificate + private key combo, an identity, to handle the user authentication.

The problem is that i need to delivery the identity using a Configuration Profile with the iPhone Configuration Utility.

After some tests i discovered that an keychain-access-groups exists but i wasn't able to access the certificate/private key neither using this.
I tried various combinations of the bundle id in the profile and as keychain-access-groups value.

Is it possible, using an application, read a certificate/private key (identity) added using a profile?

Thank you